# Is there an English translation of Degenesis?

Tags: translations, degenesis

[Degenesis](http://sixmorevodka.com/degenesis/) is a German game set in a post apocalyptic version of Europe. Is there an English translation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  You can get it [here](http://shop.sixmorevodka.com/en/degenesis/23-degenesis-rebirth-premium-edition.html).

The PDF version should be ready around mid-November 2015.

The rule set (Katharsis system) have been "fully revised" since the first edition of the game -- see in the product description. What the changes are, I cannot tell.

---

<sub><sup>I am not affiliated with the developers in any way. I have just been looking for this for a long time and thought I should share.</sup></sub>

Comment: Nice, this version looks amazing. Do you know if they use the same rules as the German v1.0? From what I remember the original rules were quite broken sadly... :/

Comment: @fgysin: My copy has not arrived and I do not own the original. However, I believe (from the web site) that the system was fixed/enhance between the editions.  I cannot give you more details than that.  Answer edited.

Comment: Might have to give the new version a try then. I just love the *feel* of the Degenesis world.

Comment: @fgysin: There is a tag for `Degenesis` now so feel free to ask a question. ☺

Comment: @Sardathrion You might accept this answer ;)

Comment: All of the existing supplements for the Rebirth edition have been released in both German and English, and according to discussions in the official Degenesis Discord, all upcoming supplements are being developed for concurrent release in both languages.

Comment: My previous note has been eclipsed by more recent developments. The VOV edition of Degenesis, the Artifacts supplement, and the upcoming Justitian supplement are all only available in English.